# html form submit using javascript vs submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have been using javascript to submit HTML forms at times for some convinence. I would like to know wheather there is any drawbacks of this approach compared to using classic form submit using a submit button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using plain HTML is better for many reasons:

- If your user does not have JavaScript enabled, or you havea JavaScript bug in your code, your form still works.
- Plain HTML forms are simpler to write, and harder to screw up
- An actual button is better semantically than a magic link or div that submits the form for you. This helps with things like tab ordering, OS integration, screen readers, and is clearer to programmers who work on the code after you.
- The browser already has battle tested code to submit forms. Why would you rewrite that code for no point? It increases risk, complexity and time.
- Not writing the JavaScript code means you have more time for other things, like not working on the code anymore.

If something already exists and works for your use case, don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Nice answer except considerations for browsers with Javascript disabled, really?

Comment: Eh, it is something to consider. I know some people who run NoScript on all sites, only whitelisting sites they trust with their JavaScript. Other times, I have been stuck in a terminal with no X, and the only browser I had was lynx - no JavaScript. Consider embedded browsers like in Steam, some music players (showing the last.fm/wikipedia page about an artist), and other similar entities. These may disable JavaScript - or not even implement it - for the sake of simplicity. Not relying on JavaScript when you can reasonably and easily do with out it is sensible.

Answer (score 0):

The only drawback I can think of is if you need to have the page reloaded because you're integrating with an older site that regenerates HTML each time... But if you're building a new system, or it already does that, in my opinion it's better. Saves bandwidth, computing time, re-rendering time, etc..
If you're talking about just submitting an HTML form, there's really no difference.

Answer (score 0):

No there are no drawbacks really. You might have more code the way you are doing it as opposed to just wrapping everything in a form and submit button but you can still take advantage of https of course and everything else the web may have to offer these days.

Comment: Thanks . Can you clarify the advantage of HTTPS ? is this advantage in submit button or javascript ?

Comment: there is no clarification required you can use https either way you go

Answer (score 0):

The most predominate disadvantage is the inability to provide functionality for visitors who have Javascript disabled. You can support both simultaneously by providing a different page to redirect to when javascript is disabled.

The following is a list of methods used to detect and react to disabled javascript:

1. `<noscript>` [The HTML noscript tag.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)
2. [Using jQuery or Javascript to set a cookie](http://www.thonky.com/javascript-and-css-guide/set-cookie/)
3. Using Javascript to hide an area using CSS.

Comment: I am surprised to hear mention of support for Javascript disabled browsers. It is truly a waste of time to spend even a moments thought on this in the year 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not a fan of HTML forms. HTML is a layout language, and a poor one at that. Keeping layout and functionality separate is a central tenet of object-oriented programming. Whether you perceive HTML and JavaScript as representing these functions in that manner is probably a personal choice. You could argue CSS is the layout.

If you're writing a simple page with little else going on, then using HTML forms isn't a bad idea.

If you are planning to write a good-sized application, with lots of nice features, then, for me at least, it would make sense to have that in one place.

If you start introducing JSON or any kind of client/server relationship beyond "here is my text or drop-down choice" then take a programmer's approach rather than a web designer. JavaScript gives you more flexibility. You can chat with the server without anything happening on the page.

If you use a library like jQuery, the coding overhead is very minimal.